# 95% CI for parameters estimation

Tags: r

how to obtain the 95% confidence interval of maximum likelihood estimate of parameter in `gev.fit`? Package of `ismev` in R.

The output of `gev.fit` :

```
$conv
[1] 0

$nllh
[1] 194.6467

$mle
[1] 93.33096665 17.53896061 -0.02969443

$se
[1] 2.92704621 2.06566895 0.09614705
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a sample dataset before we can provide help. It is difficult to give solution without dataset. You may try `confint` from `stats` packages, as it works for `glm` model, but not sure for `gev.fit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make a coherent argument that the $mle values are normally distributed with standard errors in $se then you can get 95% CI's with:

```
 LowerBounds <- gev.fit$mle - 1.96*gev.fit$se
 UpperBounds <- gev.fit$mle + 1.96*gev.fit$se
```

Comment: You could also replace the `1.96` with `qnorm(0.975)` if you want to.